# How to test for empty string on session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following test:

```
if(Session["mykey"] != string.Empty)
{...}
```

In VS.NET 2010's watch window, the value of Session["mykey"] is "".  Yet I still go into the conditional.  Do I need some other test?

--- EDIT ---
After the above runs, I do reset the object by assigning string.Empty.

Comment: Is it null?  Have you tried string.IsNullOrEmpty?

Comment: +1 Question well formed and objective !

Comment: To reset the value do not forget to use the 

Session["mykey"] `.ToString()` = string.empty;

Comment: it works just fine without .ToString().  The object will have a string with or without .ToString().

Comment: (Sorry to comment like this, but there is no messaging here, and no way to comment on deleted questions...) Regarding your question "how make m choice from n values" that you deleted, didn't you want an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, because you are comparing with the `object` of the `Sessions`not its `text`.
Do like so:

```
if(Session["mykey"].ToString() != string.Empty)
{...}
```

other way to go is:

```
if(Session["mykey"] != null)
{...}
```

Comment: Check the EDIT I added in the OP. The first condition you have is false, which I would expect.  However, the null check is true.  Is it true because this object has a value of ""? Should I initially assign empty string and only check for that and not null?

Comment: When the result of these `ifs` become true, it means that its empty, it has no value, or you didnt set up a value for it, or it's `timeout` expired... YOu can do any of these two examples that will work.. I do this way =)

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if(!string.InNullOrEmpty(Session["mykey"].ToString()))
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this throw an exception if the key is null?